# Why did I get a positive t-value in paired test when most of the new population scored lower?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, python, paired-data, scipy

I have a base population with a set of scores, then I put the subjects through training and got a corresponding set of new scores.

I want to use a paired t-test to see if the training helped/harmed. The null hypothesis is that the training has no impact. Values are listed:

```python
base = [87.0, 98.0, 100.0, 98.0, 97.0, 67.0, 32.0, 96.0, 94.0, 90.0, 91.0,
        93.0, 81.0, 82.0, 81.0]
new  = [23.0, 71.0,  51.0, 85.0, 84.0, 95.0, 42.0, 65.0, 51.0, 84.0, 92.0,
        20.0, 85.0, 22.0, 89.0]

# new - base = 
diff = [-64.0, -27.0, -49.0, -13.0, -13.0, 28.0, 10.0, -31.0, -43.0, -6.0,
          1.0, -73.0,   4.0, -60.0,   8.0]
```

You can see that the differences are mostly negative, however if I run a paired t-test through Python `scipy.stats.ttest_rel` ([Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html)):

```python
pair = stats.ttest_rel(base, new)
```

I get a t-statistic of `2.765` and a p-value of `0.015` (so, `p < 0.05`).

I was under the impression that the sign of the t-value should match the change. Can someone explain if I'm wrong, or why this happened?

Comment: This question will be marked off-topic here. I am not a python user, but could it be be that the order of variables in the function matters? Instead of `pair = stats.ttest_rel(base, new)`, why don't you try `pair = stats.ttest_rel(new, base)`?

Comment: Switching the order of new and base does indeed flip the sign of the t-value, but I am using my arguments in the right order here. I don't think this is a python question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually an implementation (i.e. a scipy) issue.

If you look at the examples section of the documentation you link to you can see that in the last example comparing rvs1 with rvs3, even though the values in rvs3 are drawn from a distribution with a mean of 8 (3 higher than rvs1's population mean of 5), the t-statistic is negative.

(with n=500 the chance of random noise flipping the direction is pretty small)

That is, that implementation is looking at the differences, a-b not b-a as you anticipated it was (and as one would reasonably expect in the absence of a specification that it was the other way). I suggest you think of the 'a' argument as standing for 'after' and the 'b' argument as standing for 'before'.

Indeed, here's an obvious check, let's do it in R where you can easily specify the differences to test:

```
> t.test(new-base)

        One Sample t-test

data:  new - base
t = -2.7652, df = 14, p-value = 0.01518
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -38.82704  -4.90629
sample estimates:
mean of x 
-21.86667
```

Here t is negative which is what you expected.

So to get what you want, pass in new and base in the other order.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not realize it was specific to the scipy implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it labeled in the documentation which vector is meant to go first.  However, in `R`, `y` is subtracted from `x`.  So:

```r
base = c(87.0, 98.0, 100.0, 98.0, 97.0, 67.0, 32.0, 96.0, 94.0, 90.0, 91.0,
         93.0, 81.0, 82.0, 81.0)
new  = c(23.0, 71.0,  51.0, 85.0, 84.0, 95.0, 42.0, 65.0, 51.0, 84.0, 92.0,
         20.0, 85.0, 22.0, 89.0)
new - base
# [1] -64 -27 -49 -13 -13  28  10 -31 -43  -6   1 -73   4 -60   8
t.test(new, base, paired=T)
#         Paired t-test
# 
# data:  new and base
# t = -2.7652, df = 14, p-value = 0.01518
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -38.82704  -4.90629
# sample estimates:
# mean of the differences 
#               -21.86667
```

There is no problem here.  You must simply have the arguments reversed.